# Task quantity in gearman queue

Tags: gearman

How to recieve current task quantity in gearman queue or active task quantity in php? I'm using library http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.gearmanclient.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in gearman